# FCM - How many topics can be created for a single firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As far as I understand from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) - a single app installation can subscribe to no more than 2000 topics.
Is there a limitation to number of topics being created by all devices together in a single firebase project?

Comment: It is incredibly irritating that this sort of info isn't provided in the docs front-and-center 